# cannot change color for barplot when combine plots

Tags: r, plot, histogram, bar-chart

I tried to plot with barplot,when `hist(breaks=200)`,barplot can in different color.But when `hist(breaks=1000)`cannot change color in barplot. And why `ylab` didn't show in the barplot when combine three plots?It's OK in single plot).

[breaks=200](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IISFO.png)
[breaks=1000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qo5kw.png)

Here is my code:breaks=1000，cannot change color.

```
def.par <- par(no.readonly = TRUE) # save default, for resetting... 
x <- pmin(3, pmax(-3, rnorm(5000)))
y <- pmin(3, pmax(-3, rnorm(5000)))
xhist <- hist(x, breaks=1000, plot=FALSE)
yhist <- hist(y, breaks=1000,plot=FALSE)
top <- max(c(xhist$density, yhist$density))
xrange <- c(-3,3)
yrange <- c(-3,3)
nf <- layout(matrix(c(2,0,1,3),2,2,byrow=TRUE), c(3,1), c(1,3), TRUE)#layout.show(nf)ZSSS

par(mar=c(3,3,0,0))
plot(x, y, xlim=xrange, ylim=yrange, xlab="T1", ylab="T2")

par(mar=c(0,3,1,1))
barplot(xhist$density, axes=TRUE, ylim=c(0, top),ylab="T3",col="red")

par(mar=c(3,0,1,1))
barplot(yhist$density, axes=TRUE, xlim=c(0, top),xlab="T4",space=0, horiz=TRUE,col="green")

par(def.par)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just change color of the border:

```
def.par <- par(no.readonly = TRUE) # save default, for resetting... 
x <- pmin(3, pmax(-3, rnorm(5000)))
y <- pmin(3, pmax(-3, rnorm(5000)))
xhist <- hist(x, breaks=100, plot=FALSE)
yhist <- hist(y, breaks=100,plot=FALSE)
top <- max(c(xhist$density, yhist$density))
xrange <- c(-3,3)
yrange <- c(-3,3)
nf <- layout(matrix(c(2,0,1,3),2,2,byrow=TRUE), c(3,1), c(1,3),TRUE)#layout.show(nf)ZSSS

par(mar=c(3,3,0,0))
plot(x, y, xlim=xrange, ylim=yrange, xlab="T1", ylab="T2")

par(mar=c(0,3,1,1))
barplot(xhist$density, axes=TRUE, ylim=c(0, top),ylab="T3",col="red", border = "red")

par(mar=c(3,0,1,1))
barplot(yhist$density, axes=TRUE, xlim=c(0, top),xlab="T4",space=0, horiz=TRUE,col="green", border = "green")
```

Comment: Thank you！But do you know why the `ylab`（T2，T3，T4） didn't show in the three plots？